# How best to use Reactive State?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a big component, I store all the information about the selected items and all the information in the store(ngrx).
There are different types in this component and I can switch between them and change information about them(via inputs). And then, at the click of a save button, send all changes to the server.

What is the best way to put changed data in the store?

- Send to the store during an onchange event (minus: a lot of dispatch)
- Send when switching between types (minus: you need to somehow check the status of the type that has been changed right now before pressing the save button)
- Or, in general, is it a bad practice to put elements that will change, and better store them to service?

---

And another question, is it correct to carry out calculations in a reducer. For example, I dispatch a list of elements in the store and I need to add a new element for the selected type. I can do this through the service, but then I need to pull out all the elements, the selected type and a few more parameters, and then perform actions and put the changed array back into the store. Or do all these actions in a reducer with known data.
Or in general, is this the wrong architectural approach to keep this list in the store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the use case it's hard to give a correct answer to this question, because it all depends on the needs.

As a rule of thumb, if the state only affects the current component, the ngrx store is not the place to store its data. An example of this is a form, it's usually an overkill to sync the form with the state in the store. That being said, if you need rehydration on the form,  it's a good use case to keep the form and the store in sync.

The minus of dispatching a lot of actions, isn't a "real" downside of it imho - the ngrx store (redux in general) is designed to handle a lot of incoming actions.

To answer the second question, yes that's were reducers are for imho - it's here where I expect some logic. See the [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go) for more info.

You can also put some "view logic" inside the selectors, like filtering, sorting, paginination, ...

Mike and Brandon gave a talk at ng-conf and they explain what should belong in state and what does not. The talk gives useful insights, [Reducing the Boilerplate with NgRx](https://youtu.be/t3jx0EC-Y3c?t=537)

Comment: I put it wrong. A big component is a component and it has many nested components, so I decided to use ngrx for data synchronization. For this reason, the forms is not entirely suitable in this case.

Thank you for your answers. I had some doubts. Thank you for video about boilerplate, @ngrx/entity very interesting thing.